# Download ARM64 package (e.g.) liblmdb-dev on amd64 system

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, arm64

Trying to download an arm64 package (liblmdb-dev) on amd64.  I know the package exists.  This is from an arm64 system:

```
apt list --installed | grep liblmdb
```

`liblmdb-dev/xenial,now 0.9.17-3 arm64 [installed]
 liblmdb0/xenial,now 0.9.17-3 arm64 [installed,automatic]`

I did this on the amd64 system:

```
  sudo dpkg --add-architecture arm64
  sudo apt-get update
```

Got some messages:

```
Ign:34 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main arm64 Packages
```

and getting the package does not work:

```
sudo apt-get install links:arm64
E: Unable to locate package links:arm64
```

I haven't gotten any arm64 packages to download.  Just using liblmdb-dev as a first package.

What steps am I missing?

Comment: Link to the "Search an download" site https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/xenial/liblmdb0 ... and package "**links**" https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/xenial/links

Comment: @KnudLarsen - Thanks for the link.  If I don't get an answer to my question I will use it to manually download the package.

Comment: It seems from the docs, that --add-architecture is supposed to do the trick, but it also seems, that it only works to add i386 architecture to an amd64 system. I have the same problem as you.